# Automate the Deletion of Cookies Set in Firefox with ANY Scripting Language Besides JS

Tags: python, powershell, firefox, cookies, scripting

Can anyone offer any guidance on this at all? Is this really so difficult? Powershell? Python? Whatever, just please send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need or want this - if it is for personal use, you can use the extension [Cookie AutoDelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/?src=search) which will auto delete all the cookies for websites you visit when you close a tab.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply, but that's not what I'm after. I'm not looking to install a program that will do it for me. I wanna learn to write the program myself. I had no idea this was going to be so difficult. After all, it only took me 2 minutes to find and copy and paste a JavaScript into a bookmark that would do it. But I don't wanna study JavaScript. Or I didn't. But now I'm thinking maybe I should. I'm starting to think it may be way more powerful pound for pound than Python or Powershell given the rigamarole I've gone through today trying to accomplish this. I've run the gauntlet.

Comment: Ah ok, I see now. I'll remove this answer since it is not really answering your question. I'd suggest you update your question with that comment to clarify it for other viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would like to automate, but in PowerShell you can delete Firefox cookies like this:

```
if (Get-Process -Name firefox -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Warning ("Firefox process(es) are still running. Please close all before removing the cookies.`r`n" +
                   "Use Get-Process -Name firefox -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue")
}
else {
    $pathRoaming = "$($env:APPDATA)\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default*"
    if (Test-Path -Path $pathRoaming -PathType Container) {
        $cookies = @()
        foreach ($path in (Resolve-Path $pathRoaming)) {
            $cookies += Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter 'cookies.sqlite*' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        # remove cookies. 
        $cookies | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf }
    }
}
```

Take off the `-WhatIf` switch from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet if you are satisfied with the results shown in the console.

Hope that helps